# How to compare days between two days and calculate number of days in Openerp?

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have this class called "**hr_company_holidays**",

```
 class hr_company_holidays(osv.osv):
  _name = "hr.company.holidays"
  _description = "hr.company.holidays"
  _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Holiday', size=256, required=True),
        'date': fields.date('Day', size=256, required=True),
    }
```

in hr_holiday module itself there is a another class called "**hr_holidays**" and in that class there is a function like this,

```
def _get_number_of_days(self, date_from, date_to):
    """Returns a float equals to the timedelta between two dates given as string."""

    DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
    from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    to_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to, DATETIME_FORMAT)
    timedelta = to_dt - from_dt
    diff_day = timedelta.days + float(timedelta.seconds) / 86400
    return diff_day
```

how to calculate number of days between **from_dt** and **to_dt** avoiding the company holidays and weekends as well... ?

I have tried bellow function and only thing I got was an error, please help me

```
def _get_number_of_days(self, date_from, date_to):
        """Returns a float equals to the timedelta between two dates given as string."""
        values = {}
        #comp_holidays = self.pool.get('company.holidays').browse(values['company_holiday_id']).date
        #print comp_holidays
        DATETIME_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        incre=timedelta(day=1)
        from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, DATETIME_FORMAT)
        to_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to, DATETIME_FORMAT)

        from_date=from_dt
        to_date=to_dt

        diff=0
        holi=0
        while from_dt <= to_dt:

            holiday_id=hr_holidays.search(self, cr, uid, from_date,context=context)
            holiday_day=hr_holidays.browse(cr, uid, holiday_id, context=context).date 

            if from_date == holiday_day:
                holi += 1
                from_date += incre
            else:
                from_date += incre    



        timedelta = to_dt - from_dt + holi


        diff_day = timedelta.days + float(timedelta.seconds) / 86400
```